# JSON dot notation to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, syntax, notation

I am using JSON within my javascript and I am trying to get a string value for the dot notation representation.

For example `AAA.BBB[0].CCC.DDD[5].EEE` = 123 in JSON dot notation format.

But I want to get the value `AAA.BBB[0].CCC.DDD[5].EEE` as a String so I can save it for later use to allow me to modify my JSON code directly.

Is there a method in Javascript or jQuery that can return a string value representation?

*EDIT
I am converting JSON data into a list structure, and I want to save the `AAA.BBB[0].CCC.DDD[5].EEE` format as the id so when a user modifies the content of that list item it modifies the JSON data directly. Would there be a better way to save the location in the id?

Comment: A bit more informative than adeneo's answer perhaps: http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: There is no such thing as "JSON dot notation format".

Comment: I am converting JSON data into a list structure, and I want to save the "AAA.BBB[0].CCC.DDD[5].EEE" format as the id so when a user modifies the content of that list item it modifies the JSON data directly. Would there be a better way to save the location in the id?

Comment: What do you mean by "modifies the JSON data directly"?  What *exactly* are you working with here?  JSON is a *string representation* of data.  Do you actually have a JSON string, or do you just have a JavaScript object?

Comment: I have a JSON object that essentially contains a huge nested structure. Currently its being outputted as a html list. I want to set it up so that when a specific node is clicked and then modified by the user, the json code is updated at the given node (which is a location saved to the id of the li)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just store a reference to an inner-portion of it? Storing it as a string doesn't make much sense. If you just want a shorter way of accessing it, storing a reference makes more sense.

```
var theCollection = AAA.BBB[0].CCC.DDD[5];
alert( theCollection.EEE );
```

this reference can then be stored on an element and retrieved later.

```
$(someelement).data("jsonref",theCollection);
var data = $(someelement).data("jsonref");
alert(data.EEE);
data.EEE = "foobar";
data = $(someelement).data("jsonref");
alert( data.EEE );
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to say. This is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var j_string = JSON.stringify(AAA.BBB[0].CCC.DDD[5].EEE);
```

If you just want the value returned as a string do this:

```
var j_string_value = AAA.BBB[0].CCC.DDD[5].EEE.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `eval` on the string if you are looking to execute an operation on that path, but `eval` is pretty dangerous since it allows arbitrary code execution. If you want to JSON stringify the entire structure, there is [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) which is a standard feature in most new browsers and Doug Crockford has his own take on it for older browsers [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: The console allows arbitrary code execution, even if you don't include any `eval` calls in your program.